# How to combine IObservable sequences in UniRx/Rx.NET?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reactivex, rx.net, unirx

I'm using the UniRx flavor of Reactive Extensions for the Unity3D game engine.
Unity uses C#, so I guess it's similar to Rx.NET.

I need a more beautiful way of checking when several observable sequences complete.

In the example below, one of the sequences is dependent on the outcome of the first (since it needs an integer for `processID`).

The observables are both of type `IObservable<string>`.

```
var processListObservable = APIBuilder
    .GetProcessList(authInfo.Token, authInfo.PlatformURL, (int)product.Id)
    .Subscribe(listJson =>
    {
        processList = ProcessList.FromJson(listJson);
        int processID = (int)processList.Processes[0].ProcessDataId;

        //Retrieve Detailed information of the first entry
        var processDetailsObservable = APIBuilder
            .GetProcessDetails(token, platformURL, product.Id, processID)
            .Subscribe(detailsJson =>
            {
                processData = ProcessData.FromJson(detailsJson);
                SetupPlotView();
            });
    });
```

Any hint would be highly appreciated. Also some suggestions to solve the same scenario minus the dependency on the result of the first sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting your code into the `Subscribe` handler, you could make it part of the sequence. You could use the `Select` operator in order to project each `listJson` to an `IObservable<string>` (resulting to a nested `IObservable<IObservable<string>>`), and then flatten the sequence by using either the `Concat` or the `Merge` operator, depending on whether you want to prevent or allow concurrency.

```
var processListObservable = APIBuilder
    .GetProcessList(authInfo.Token, authInfo.PlatformURL, (int)product.Id)
    .Select(listJson =>
    {
        var processList = ProcessList.FromJson(listJson);
        int processID = (int)processList.Processes[0].ProcessDataId;
        return APIBuilder.GetProcessDetails(token, platformURL, product.Id, processID);
    })
    .Concat() // or .Merge() to allow concurrency
    .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current) // Optional
    .Do(detailsJson =>
    {
        var processData = ProcessData.FromJson(detailsJson);
        SetupPlotView(processData);
    });

await processListObservable.DefaultIfEmpty(); // Start and await the operation
```

The `await` in the final line will cause an implicit subscription to the `processListObservable`, and your code will execute as a side-effect of this subscription.

Comment: Caution, the `Concat` operator [behaves wierdly](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1634) in the current version of the Rx library (5.0.0). My advice is to use the equivalent `Merge(1)` operator instead, until the issue with the `Concat` is fixed. The `1` is the value of the `maxConcurrent` parameter. Setting this parameter to `1` means no concurrency.